# AKS: --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges filter

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a trouble with enabling `--api-server-authorized-ip-ranges` feature, let me describe my case:

1. I have AKS without enabled feature, but want to add it using this command:

```
az aks update --resource-group test-aks-service-rg -n test-aksCluster --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges 1.2.3.4/32
```

I got a result that ip address has been successfully added as allowed for API.

2. Then, I'm trying to get logs of the pods, but I'm getting timeout issue:

```
Error from server ... dail tcp ... i/o timeout.
```

What is wrong with my configuration? How to properly add auth ip ranges?

**Note:** I verified that my ip outbound address is 1.2.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my fault, I have missed important thing in Microsoft documentation. An answer is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/aks/api-server-authorized-ip-ranges

I forgot to add firewall public ip addresses into auth ip ranges list.

The following addresses must be in the list, to get it work:

- The firewall public IP address
- Any range that represents networks that you'll administer the cluster from
- If you are using Azure Dev Spaces on your AKS cluster, you have to allow additional ranges based on your region.

Comment: Where to find that firewall public IP address of the AKS ?

Comment: You can find firewall public IP address in the Azure portal. Azure > Firewall > Public IP Configuration.